# Passing object to context cause crash on read context

Tags: go

I have been playing with GO for a few days now, considering to rewrite a DotNetCore microservice app on kubernetes in GO.
First of all i'm suprised how easy and fast dev on GO is.

As the project is a multitenant SAAS app, my first attempt in GO is to have a minimal multitenant api running. I added a middleware to resolve the tenant and store it in the context. When reading from the context, the application crash unless i make a copy of the tenant object.

Works => `ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, &Tenant{ ... })`

Not works => `ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, &tenant)`

Should i always make a copy or is there an other reasson causing the crash?

Comments / suggestions how to improve my code or do things different in GO always welcome :)

```
type Tenant struct {
    Id          string
    Name        string
    Host        string
    VirtualPath string
}

var allTenants []Tenant

func tenantResolverMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        path := r.URL.Path
        segments := strings.Split(path, "/")
        virtualPath := ""
        if len(segments) >= 1 {
            virtualPath = segments[1]
        }

        tenant := findTenant(r.Host, virtualPath)
        if tenant == nil && virtualPath != "" {
            tenant = findTenant(r.Host, "")
        }
        if tenant != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Tenant resolve: %s\r\n", tenant.Name)

            if tenant.VirtualPath != "" {
                fmt.Printf("Rewrite tenant uri\r\n")
                path = "/" + strings.Join(segments[2:], "/")
                r.URL.Path = path
            }

            ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
            defer cancel()

            ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, &Tenant{
                Id: tenant.Id,
                Name: tenant.Name,
                Host: tenant.Host,
                VirtualPath: tenant.VirtualPath,
            })
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
        } else {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        }
    })
}

func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    contextData := r.Context().Value(tenantKey)
    tenant, ok := contextData.(*Tenant)

    if ok {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "test %v", tenant.Name)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "NOK")
    }
}
```

Comment: „Not works“ is not a problem description.

Comment: tenant, ok := contextData.(*Tenant)
ok = false when passing &tenant instead of copy object

ah, maybe my title is wrong. First i was not doing the "ok" check and then the app crash, now i avoid crash by checking if casting the object is ok, but the question remains, why can't i cast when passing an object instead of making a copy

Comment: Come up with a minimal example showing the problem. What you describe is impossible.

Comment: https://github.com/DeborggraeveR/go-tenancy


See service.go line 65 where context is set

See service.go line 86 where context is read

Comment: Oh, fixed the issue by looking at the entire code again. findTenant returns pointer, so i had the set the value by "ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, tenant)" instead of "ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, &tenant)" to cast it to "*Tenant" when reading it: https://github.com/DeborggraeveR/go-tenancy/commit/e4cd91e1f4336ddb102f7910b35e023777b336f0#diff-c52daedaeda258db15ec11d57bbf299412a20328f6cd026980ef07f01960dd3a

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. I've been trying to reproduce this for the past 15 min unsuccessfully. Was wondering if it was a `interface{}` issue with contexts and messing up the GC. Though it's definitely not a stack/heap issue the more that I look at it, since each middleware func lives for the entire request (since it's calling the next one in the chain).

Answer (score -3):

You need to declare the `tenant` var to be a pointer.

```
tenant := &Tenant{
    Id: tenant.Id,
    Name: tenant.Name,
    Host: tenant.Host,
    VirtualPath: tenant.VirtualPath,
}

ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, tenantKey, tenant)
```

The problem is due to how variables are allocated.

The difference is that if you declare `tenant` to be a value and not a pointer, it will be allocated onto the stack, so once the function exits that variable no longer exists. But if you declare it as a pointer, it gets allocated onto the heap, and won't become freed when the function exits.

FYI, this is why GC is important. Once something is allocated onto the heap, it stays there unless it's freed. Whether that's freeing something manually like in C or relying on Go's runtime GC to cleanup vars that no longer are being referenced.

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: @Volker Can you provide a link that explains it correctly?

Comment: Go as a language has no stack and no heap and it never affects correctness of a program if a certain compiler puts values on the the heap or stack.

Comment: @Volker https://go.dev/doc/faq#stack_or_heap it's literally in the FAQ